# Generate Random String in PL/SQL (oracle 12c)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I'm trying to generate a Random String using PL/SQL with only 2 fixed words. It's this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "only 2 fixed words"? Can you give an example (update the question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SQL> with
  2  -- two fixed words
  3  test as
  4    (select 'fixed words' col from dual),
  5  -- split them to rows
  6  inter as
  7    (select level lvl, regexp_substr(col, '.', 1, level) let
  8     from test
  9     connect by level <= length(col)
 10    )
 11  -- aggregate them back, randomly
 12  select listagg(let, '') within group (order by dbms_random.value(1, max_lvl)) result
 13  from inter
 14  join (select max(lvl) max_lvl from inter) on 1 = 1;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
reiosdwxf d

SQL> /

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fe ixoddrws

SQL> /

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 wdxeorsdfi

SQL>
```